# How do I activate JavaScript earlier in DOM in a specific DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

I am trying to build a simple JavaScript program where you can click on a particular fruit from a list and it will give some information about the fruit and also load a 3d rendered model into a DIV Window.

I am nearly finished but don't understand how I can activate the script within the div based on what the user clicks on.  Right now I am just trying to test it by having it activate a console log.

One method I'm trying is putting some script in the div and activating it by putting in a statement that activates when its value is changed but I haven't been successful with that yet either.  This is my first project so there may be a lot if idiotic things in here - please critique me on those as well

I have it currently set up to activate on Peach

```js
    //have clicked fruit items relay to function
    var apple = document.getElementById('apple').onclick = apple;
    var banana = document.getElementById('banana').onclick = banana;
    var strawberry = document.getElementById('strawberry').onclick = strawberry;
    var orange = document.getElementById('orange').onclick = orange;
    var pineapple = document.getElementById('pineapple').onclick = pineapple;
    var blueberry = document.getElementById('blueberry').onclick = blueberry;
    var grape = document.getElementById('grape').onclick = grape;
    var lemon = document.getElementById('lemon').onclick = lemon;
    var kiwi = document.getElementById('kiwi').onclick = kiwi;
    var watermelon = document.getElementById('watermelon').onclick = watermelon;
    var peach = document.getElementById('peach').onclick = peach;
    
    //redefine variables --> reset styling
    function styleReset() {
        
        var apple = document.getElementById("apple");
        apple.style.color = "hotpink";
        
        var banana = document.getElementById("banana");
        banana.style.color = "hotpink";
        
        var strawberry = document.getElementById("strawberry");
        strawberry.style.color = "hotpink";
       
        var orange = document.getElementById("orange");
        orange.style.color = "hotpink";
        
        var pineapple = document.getElementById("pineapple");
        pineapple.style.color = "hotpink";
        
        var blueberry = document.getElementById("blueberry");
        blueberry.style.color = "hotpink";
        
        var grape = document.getElementById("grape");
        grape.style.color = "hotpink";
        
        var lemon = document.getElementById("lemon");
        lemon.style.color = "hotpink";
        
        var kiwi = document.getElementById("kiwi");
        kiwi.style.color = "hotpink";
       
        var watermelon = document.getElementById("watermelon");
        watermelon.style.color = "hotpink";
       
        var peach = document.getElementById("peach");
        peach.style.color = "hotpink";
    }

    //define each fruit function
    function apple(){
        console.log("loading apple");
        styleReset();
        var apple = document.getElementById('apple');
        apple.style.color = "red";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Apple";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "An apple is a sweet, edible fruit produced by an apple tree (Malus pumila). Apple trees are cultivated worldwide and are the most widely grown species in the genus Malus. The tree originated in Central Asia, where its wild ancestor, Malus sieversii, is still found today. Apples have been grown for thousands of years in Asia and Europe and were brought to North America by European colonists.";
    }

    function banana(){
        console.log("loading banana");
        styleReset();
        var banana = document.getElementById('banana');
        banana.style.color = "gold";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Banana";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "A banana is an edible fruit – botanically a berry – produced by several kinds of large herbaceous flowering plants in the genus Musa. In some countries, bananas used for cooking may be called 'plantains.' Musa species are native to tropical Indomalaya and Australia, and are likely to have been first domesticated in Papua New Guinea. They are grown in 135 countries and the world's largest producers of bananas are India and China";
    }

    function strawberry(){
        console.log("loading strawberry");
        styleReset();
        var strawberry = document.getElementById('strawberry');
        strawberry.style.color = "red";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Strawberry";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "The garden strawberry is a widely grown hybrid species of the genus Fragaria, collectively known as the strawberries. It is cultivated worldwide for its fruit. The fruit is widely appreciated for its characteristic aroma, bright red color, juicy texture, and sweetness.";
    }

    function orange(){
        console.log("loading orange");
        styleReset();
        var orange = document.getElementById('orange');
        orange.style.color = "peru";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Orange";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "The orange is the fruit of the citrus species Citrus × sinensis in the family Rutaceae.  It is known as the 'Sweet Orange.' It originated in ancient China and the earliest mention of the sweet orange was in Chinese literature in 314 BC. As of 1987, orange trees were found to be the most cultivated fruit tree in the world. In 2014, 70.9 million tonnes of oranges were grown worldwide, with Brazil producing 24% of the world total followed by China and India. Oranges are infertile and reproduce asexually.";
    }

    function pineapple(){
        console.log("loading pineapple");
        styleReset();
        var pineapple = document.getElementById('pineapple');
        pineapple.style.color = "yellow";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Pineapple";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "The word 'pineapple' in English was first recorded to describe the reproductive organs of conifer trees (now termed pine cones). When European explorers encountered this tropical fruit in the Americas, they called them 'pineapples' (first referenced in 1664, for resemblance to pine cones). The plant is indigenous to South America and is said to originate from the area between southern Brazil and Paraguay. Columbus encountered the pineapple in 1493 on the leeward island of Guadeloupe. He called it piña de Indes, meaning 'pine of the Indians', and brought it back with him to Spain.";
    }

    function blueberry(){
        console.log("loading blueberry");
        styleReset();
        var blueberry = document.getElementById('blueberry');
        blueberry.style.color = "blue";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Blueberry";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "Blueberries are perennial flowering plants with blue– or purple–colored berries. They are classified in the section Cyanococcus within the genus Vaccinium. Commercial 'blueberries' are all native to North America. They are covered in a protective coating of powdery epicuticular wax, colloquially known as the 'bloom'. They have a sweet taste when mature, with variable acidity. ";
    }

    function grape(){
        console.log("loading grape");
        styleReset();
        var grape = document.getElementById('grape');
        grape.style.color = "purple";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Grape";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "A grape is a fruit, botanically a berry, of the deciduous woody vines of the flowering plant genus Vitis. Grapes are a non-climacteric type of fruit, generally occurring in clusters. The cultivation of the domesticated grape began 6,000–8,000 years ago in the Near East.[1] Yeast, one of the earliest domesticated microorganisms, occurs naturally on the skins of grapes, leading to the discovery of alcoholic drinks such as wine. The earliest archeological evidence for a dominant position of wine-making in human culture dates from 8,000 years ago in Georgia.";
    }

    function lemon(){
        console.log("loading lemon");
        styleReset();
        var lemon = document.getElementById('lemon');
        lemon.style.color = "yellow";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Lemon";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "The lemon, Citrus limon Osbeck, is a species of small evergreen tree in the flowering plant family Rutaceae, native to South Asia, primarily North eastern India. The juice of the lemon is about 5% to 6% citric acid, with a pH of around 2.2, giving it a sour taste. The distinctive sour taste of lemon juice makes it a key ingredient in drinks and foods such as lemonade and lemon meringue pie.";
    }

    function kiwi(){
        console.log("loading kiwi");
        styleReset();
        var kiwi = document.getElementById('kiwi');
        kiwi.style.color = "green";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Kiwi";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "Kiwi is the edible berry of several species of woody vines in the genus Actinidia. It has a fibrous, dull greenish-brown skin and bright green or golden flesh with rows of tiny, black, edible seeds. Kiwifruit is native to north-central and eastern China. The first recorded description of the kiwifruit dates to 12th century China during the Song dynasty.  China produced 56% of the world total of kiwifruit in 2016.";
    }

    function watermelon(){
        console.log("loading watermelon");
        styleReset();
        var watermelon = document.getElementById('watermelon');
        watermelon.style.color = "crimson";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Watermelon";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "Citrullus lanatus is a plant species in the family Cucurbitaceae, a vine-like flowering plant originating in West Africa. It is cultivated for its fruit. There is evidence from seeds in Pharaoh tombs of watermelon cultivation in Ancient Egypt. Watermelon is grown in tropical and subtropical areas worldwide for its large edible fruit, also known as a watermelon, which is a special kind of berry with a hard rind and no internal division, botanically called a pepo.";
    }

    function peach(){
        console.log("loading peach");
        styleReset();
        var peach = document.getElementById('peach');
        peach.style.color = "peru";
        fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
        fruitName.innerText = "Peach";
        fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
        fruitDesc.innerText = "The peach (Prunus persica) is a deciduous tree native to the region of Northwest China between the Tarim Basin and the north slopes of the Kunlun Mountains, where it was first domesticated and cultivated. The specific name persica refers to its widespread cultivation in Persia (modern-day Iran), from where it was transplanted to Europe. China alone produced 58% of the world's total for peaches and nectarines in 2016.";
        //activate 3d view window
        var x = document.getElementById('x');
        x.innerHTML = 1;
    }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}



.container {
background-color: beige;
width: 600px;
min-height: 550px;
border-radius: 30px;
margin: 40px auto;
}

.title {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    color: indianred;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.box3d {
    float: right;
    height: 225px;
    width: 280px;
    background-color: slategray;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 25px 50px 0px 0px;
}

.desc {
    float: right;
    height: 225px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 25px 50px 0px 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.fruitlist {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 30px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

li {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: purple;
    font-size: 18px;
}

li:hover {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: hotpink;
}

#fruitName {
    color: blue;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-bottom: solid 3px blue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#fruitDesc {
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>FruityView</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fruitstyle.css">
</head>

<body>
    
<div class = "container">

<h1 class = "title">FruityView</h1>
<!--3D MODEL VIEW WINDOW-->
<div class="box3d" id = "box3d">
    
    <p id='x'>0</p>
    
    <script>
       
      //this doesn't work - maybe I could do some sort of for loop that could retest it? 
      var x = document.getElementById('x');
       console.log(x); 
        function view3d() {
            console.log("view function activated");
        }
        
        if (x == 1) {
            view3d();
        }
      
        //this doesn't work - I know it would if it came after the list but I don't want to do that
        /*var peach = document.getElementById('peach').onclick = peach;
        peach() {
            console.log("successful activation");
        }
        */

    </script>

</div>
<br>

<!--SELECTION LIST-->
<ul class="fruitlist">

    <li id = "apple">Apple</li>
    <li id = "banana">Banana</li>
    <li id = "strawberry">Strawberry</li>
    <li id = "orange">Orange</li>
    <li id = "pineapple">Pineapple</li>
    <li id = "blueberry">Blueberry</li>
    <li id = "grape">Grape</li>
    <li id = "lemon">Lemon</li>
    <li id = "kiwi">Kiwi</li>
    <li id = "watermelon">Watermelon</li>
    <li id = "peach">Peach</li>

</ul>

<!--NAME AND DESCRIPTION-->
<div class="desc">
    <h3 id = "fruitName">Welcome to FruityView</h3>
    <p id = "fruitDesc">Please pick a fruit</p>
</div>

</div>

<script src="fruityview.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by `how I can activate the script within the div`?

Comment: Yes.  I am trying to get the 3d rendered model to load and appear in that specific div.  The one in the top right that just appears as a gray box.

Comment: I think your main trouble is you are using each fruit name twice, once when fetching your elements, and once to define each function, like `var apple = ...` and `function apple() {...`. I think those are colliding.

Answer (score 1):

Consider storing your fruit information as data and using some common shared functions to render.

Can you tell us where the 3D data is coming from and we can add that functionality.

```js
let fruits = [{
    name: "apple",
    description: "An apple is a sweet, edible fruit produced by an apple tree (Malus pumila). Apple trees are cultivated worldwide and are the most widely grown species in the genus Malus. The tree originated in Central Asia, where its wild ancestor, Malus sieversii, is still found today. Apples have been grown for thousands of years in Asia and Europe and were brought to North America by European colonists.",
    color: "green"
  },
  {
    name: "banana",
    description: "A banana is an edible fruit – botanically a berry – produced by several kinds of large herbaceous flowering plants in the genus Musa. In some countries, bananas used for cooking may be called 'plantains.' Musa species are native to tropical Indomalaya and Australia, and are likely to have been first domesticated in Papua New Guinea. They are grown in 135 countries and the world's largest producers of bananas are India and China",
    color: "gold"
  },
  {
    name: "strawberry",
    description: "The garden strawberry is a widely grown hybrid species of the genus Fragaria, collectively known as the strawberries. It is cultivated worldwide for its fruit. The fruit is widely appreciated for its characteristic aroma, bright red color, juicy texture, and sweetness.",
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    name: "orange",
    description: "The orange is the fruit of the citrus species Citrus × sinensis in the family Rutaceae.  It is known as the 'Sweet Orange.' It originated in ancient China and the earliest mention of the sweet orange was in Chinese literature in 314 BC. As of 1987, orange trees were found to be the most cultivated fruit tree in the world. In 2014, 70.9 million tonnes of oranges were grown worldwide, with Brazil producing 24% of the world total followed by China and India. Oranges are infertile and reproduce asexually.",
    color: "peru"
  },
  {
    name: "pineapple",
    description: "The word 'pineapple' in English was first recorded to describe the reproductive organs of conifer trees (now termed pine cones). When European explorers encountered this tropical fruit in the Americas, they called them 'pineapples' (first referenced in 1664, for resemblance to pine cones). The plant is indigenous to South America and is said to originate from the area between southern Brazil and Paraguay. Columbus encountered the pineapple in 1493 on the leeward island of Guadeloupe. He called it piña de Indes, meaning 'pine of the Indians', and brought it back with him to Spain.",
    color: "yellow"
  },
  {
    name: "blueberry",
    description: "Blueberries are perennial flowering plants with blue– or purple–colored berries. They are classified in the section Cyanococcus within the genus Vaccinium. Commercial 'blueberries' are all native to North America. They are covered in a protective coating of powdery epicuticular wax, colloquially known as the 'bloom'. They have a sweet taste when mature, with variable acidity.",
    color: "blue"
  },
  {
    name: "grape",
    description: "A grape is a fruit, botanically a berry, of the deciduous woody vines of the flowering plant genus Vitis. Grapes are a non-climacteric type of fruit, generally occurring in clusters. The cultivation of the domesticated grape began 6,000–8,000 years ago in the Near East.[1] Yeast, one of the earliest domesticated microorganisms, occurs naturally on the skins of grapes, leading to the discovery of alcoholic drinks such as wine. The earliest archeological evidence for a dominant position of wine-making in human culture dates from 8,000 years ago in Georgia.",
    color: "purple"
  },
  {
    name: "lemon",
    description: "The lemon, Citrus limon Osbeck, is a species of small evergreen tree in the flowering plant family Rutaceae, native to South Asia, primarily North eastern India. The juice of the lemon is about 5% to 6% citric acid, with a pH of around 2.2, giving it a sour taste. The distinctive sour taste of lemon juice makes it a key ingredient in drinks and foods such as lemonade and lemon meringue pie.",
    color: "yellow"
  },
  {
    name: "kiwi",
    description: "Kiwi is the edible berry of several species of woody vines in the genus Actinidia. It has a fibrous, dull greenish-brown skin and bright green or golden flesh with rows of tiny, black, edible seeds. Kiwifruit is native to north-central and eastern China. The first recorded description of the kiwifruit dates to 12th century China during the Song dynasty.  China produced 56% of the world total of kiwifruit in 2016.",
    color: "green"
  },
  {
    name: "watermelon",
    description: "Citrullus lanatus is a plant species in the family Cucurbitaceae, a vine-like flowering plant originating in West Africa. It is cultivated for its fruit. There is evidence from seeds in Pharaoh tombs of watermelon cultivation in Ancient Egypt. Watermelon is grown in tropical and subtropical areas worldwide for its large edible fruit, also known as a watermelon, which is a special kind of berry with a hard rind and no internal division, botanically called a pepo.",
    color: "crimson"
  },
  {
    name: "peach",
    description: "The peach (Prunus persica) is a deciduous tree native to the region of Northwest China between the Tarim Basin and the north slopes of the Kunlun Mountains, where it was first domesticated and cultivated. The specific name persica refers to its widespread cultivation in Persia (modern-day Iran), from where it was transplanted to Europe. China alone produced 58% of the world's total for peaches and nectarines in 2016.",
    color: "peru"
  }
];

function resetStyle() {
  document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(x => x.style.color = 'hotpink');
}

function setFruit(fruit) {
  console.log(`loading ${fruit.name}`);

  let elem = document.getElementById(fruit.name);
  elem.style.color = fruit.color;
  fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
  fruitName.innerText = fruit.name;
  fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
  fruitDesc.innerText = fruit.description;
  //activate 3d view window
  var x = document.getElementById('x');
  x.innerHTML = 1;
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('li')) {
    resetStyle();
    setFruit(fruits.find(f => f.name === e.target.id));
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.container {
  background-color: beige;
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 550px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.title {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  color: indianred;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.box3d {
  float: right;
  height: 225px;
  width: 280px;
  background-color: slategray;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px 50px 0px 0px;
}

.desc {
  float: right;
  height: 225px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px 50px 0px 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fruitlist {
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 30px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: purple;
  font-size: 18px;
}

li:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: hotpink;
}

#fruitName {
  color: blue;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#fruitDesc {
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>FruityView</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fruitstyle.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <h1 class="title">FruityView</h1>
    <!--3D MODEL VIEW WINDOW-->
    <div class="box3d" id="box3d">

      <p id='x'>0</p>

      <script>
        //this doesn't work - maybe I could do some sort of for loop that could retest it? 
        var x = document.getElementById('x');
        console.log(x);

        function view3d() {
          console.log("view function activated");
        }

        if (x == 1) {
          view3d();
        }

        //this doesn't work - I know it would if it came after the list but I don't want to do that
        /*var peach = document.getElementById('peach').onclick = peach;
        peach() {
            console.log("successful activation");
        }
        */
      </script>

    </div>
    <br>

    <!--SELECTION LIST-->
    <ul class="fruitlist">

      <li id="apple">Apple</li>
      <li id="banana">Banana</li>
      <li id="strawberry">Strawberry</li>
      <li id="orange">Orange</li>
      <li id="pineapple">Pineapple</li>
      <li id="blueberry">Blueberry</li>
      <li id="grape">Grape</li>
      <li id="lemon">Lemon</li>
      <li id="kiwi">Kiwi</li>
      <li id="watermelon">Watermelon</li>
      <li id="peach">Peach</li>

    </ul>

    <!--NAME AND DESCRIPTION-->
    <div class="desc">
      <h3 id="fruitName">Welcome to FruityView</h3>
      <p id="fruitDesc">Please pick a fruit</p>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm using a library called 'three.js'.   I am still very new to it and don't completely understand it yet and how to load my own models to it.

Comment: here is an example of first parts of it:                                                                      //set setting
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
//set camera perspective
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,1000);
//config render
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
//set background color
renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
//set size of renderer
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

//create canvas element with renderer settings
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

Comment: sorry I am not used to using StackOverflow

Comment: no problem using Three. Thats cool. Look at how we changed to a generic method to load the fruit name and description. Passing in the fruit from the array. You need to do similar now with you Three.js method. You might need to add extra data to the fruit array as well.

Comment: awesome thanks!  I figured there would be a better way of doing that

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there's a misunderstanding of what `<script>` does and why you cannot use `document.getElementById` before the list. So I'll try to explain.

Anything you put directly in `<script>` will be executed right away when the browser reads it.

That means any elements in the DOM following that script don't exist yet, which is the reason why `document.getElementById()` will not find such an element.

So the reason it fails is not that "JavaScript isn't active", it's that the element with the ID is not existing yet.

If you want to declare code in a script element, and call it only later, you would just wrap it in a function, like so:

```
<script>
function callMeLater() {
  var x = document.getElementById('x');
}
</script>
…
<script>
/* now all above elements exist */
callMeLater();
</script>
```

Further, it is not necessary to put a script inside the `<div>` which will contain the model. You can inject HTML into an element by means of [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) any time (once it exists in the DOM).

```
document.getElementById('box3d').innerHTML = 3dModelHtml;
```

Last, I would like to mention that you have a lot of duplicate code, which you should avoid by all means. Replace them with functions and objects where you store data.

For example, use an object to store fruitIds together with their descriptions:

```
var fruitDescriptions = {
  'apple': "An apple is a sweet, edible fruit produced by an apple tree (Malus pumila). Apple trees are cultivated worldwide and are the most widely grown species in the genus Malus. The tree originated in Central Asia, where its wild ancestor, Malus sieversii, is still found today. Apples have been grown for thousands of years in Asia and Europe and were brought to North America by European colonists.",
   'banana': "…",
}
```

Then, you can iterate over the fruits with [for…in](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to bind the event handlers to each fruit and reset it's styles:

```
for(fruitId in fruitDescriptions) {
  var fruit = document.getElementById(fruitId);
  fruit.click = function() { fruit(fruitId); }
  fruit.style.color = "hotpink";
}
```

(You need another function for the event handler, to pass the parameter `fruitId` to the actual handler)

Finally, refactor your duplicate functions to use the fruit as a parameter:

```
function fruit(fruitId){
    console.log("loading " + fruitId);
    styleReset();
    var fruit = document.getElementById(fruitId);
    fruit.style.color = "red";
    fruitName = document.getElementById('fruitName');
    fruitName.innerText = fruitId;
    fruitDesc = document.getElementById('fruitDesc');
    fruitDesc.innerText = fruitDescriptions[fruitId];
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So I could just do all the rendering code in that same JS file at the end and then just insert it afterwards?  Yeah I plan on refactoring all of those. I was initially confused what I was doing while I was accidentally creating things with same name

Comment: Yes, you can (and it's good practice to) do all the logic afterwards. "Separation of concerns" is a basic development principle, so you'd separate your document structure and your logic.

Comment: For the refactoring, the other answer gives a great example.

Comment: Thank you, this clarified a lot for me!